# Saving image in SQL Server 2014 and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, sql-server-2014

I have problem with saving a jpeg image to SQL Server

This is my code

```
 string con_string = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["con_string"];
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conobj = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(con_string);

 string sql = "INSERT INTO Docs (nid,photo) VALUES (@nid,@photo)";
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conobj); 
 int length = photoupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;

 //create a byte array to store the binary image data
 byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];

 //store the currently selected file in memeory
 HttpPostedFile img = photoupload.PostedFile;

 //set the binary data
 img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nid",nid_lbl .Text );
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary ).Value = imgbyte;
 cmd.Connection = conobj;

 conobj.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conobj.Close();
```

and `docs` table structure is:

```
Column Datatype
nid    char
photo  varbinary(max)
```

A new row add to docs table when I press save button but after retrieve using handler it shows nothing to image control

My retrieve handler is correct, maybe the problem is with save procedure?

Please help!

Comment: take a look http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020929.asp

Comment: An easy way to save images to a SQL server, is to format the image to base64 strings, and save them as so in the database.

Comment: When you say 'a new row add(ed) to docs table', does the varbinary field actually contain data ?